# Save a credit card via PayPal REST APIs

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to save a credit card for use later (much later) with the REST APIs and get a token back that I can use for future purchases.  We're building a platform of a service based organization and are trying to use PayPal as the payment processor and my previous attempts didn't work.  I was trying to use saved tokens in the vault (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/payment-tokens-api/cards/), but after some of the cards I'd stored stopping working, I'm being told that the tokens have a very short life span (though I can't find how long or any documentation to that effect).  Any other ideas?  I have two use cases that I'm trying to cover.  First is just saving the payment method for later, to make paying the next invoice easier.  The second is allowing automatic payment of invoices.  Invoices aren't generated on any kind of schedule or even for the same amount, so subscriptions really aren't going to get me there.  I'm trying to do all of this within my own UI, so I'd rather not have to kick the user over to a PayPal interface to pay.  And, even if I did that for the manual payment option, I don't think that would allow for the automatic option if the user chooses to do so.

Thoughts or options?  API calls that I (apparently) haven't found?

Comment: Do use the Payment Methods Tokens API, v3/vault. That is what it is for.

Comment: @PrestonPHX That's what i'm using, but I was told by MTS support "In vault side, setup token can only be stored in cache for a period of time. When the setup token is expired, you can not use it to create the payment token."  I've been having an issue with my saved tokens not being found, and this is what they came up with as the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> **setup** token can only be stored in cache for a period of time

Use the [Payment Method Tokens](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/payment-tokens-api/cards/) (v3/vault) API to create a payment token.

Save the **payment token**.

Comment: i've made changes so that i'm saving the payment token instead.  now, i was able to get one purchase to go through.  but i came back a couple of hours later and i'm getting a 403 error back.  error message states "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions."  any other ideas?